# Where do you place the data model in a dojo application?

Tags: javascript, dojo

My dilemma is that it is recommended in the dojo documentation that AMD modules should not set or read global variables.  However say your data model contains properties used by many separate widgets (so its a shared model), it is not reasonable to expect each widget to hold its own instance of the data model object. So where do you put it so that all widgets that need to get and set properties or watch property changes can do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Singletone Pattern.

> Singletons reduce the need for global variables which is particularly
>   important in JavaScript because it limits namespace pollution and
>   associated risk of name collisions. [Source](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/singleton-design-pattern).

To implement Singletone Pattern in Dojo you could create an AMD module which is a single tone object.

In the following example you have definition of an AMD module called `App`.
A "public" property `data` could contain any objects representing your shared data, so you can use it within your widgets which are separated AMD modules.

Function `init` could be used to initialize the single tone object and populate property `data` (for example making a request to your Server API).

`bootstrap` AMD module (which is the entry point of your app), shows how to load for the first time `app` AMD module and initialize it, from that point whenever you need to get the "shared" data within your widget you can request app and data like this `app().data`;

---

app.js file

```
define([

], function (

    ) {
    'use strict';
    var _instance;
    function _App() {
    }
    _App.prototype = {
        // data: [public] Object
        //      Data for your app.
        data: null,
        init: function () {
            // summary:
            //      Initializes and fetch some data from the server.
        }
    };
    return function _getSingleton() {
        // summary:
        //      Gets singleton object.
        return (_instance = (_instance || new _App()));
    };
});
```

---

bootstrap.js file

```
require([
    'app'
   ], function (
    app
     ) {
    'use strict';
    // module:
    //      bootstrap
    // summary:
    //      Application bootstrap with the main responsibility to initiate  modules (single tones).
    // initializes module app
    app().init();    
});
```

Comment: _App has to be a function?

Comment: @erotavlas  In javascript a function is a first class object, with the following code _App has to be a function. I hope this answer helped you out. Please let me know if you need more infos.